# Ruby on Rails / asset pipeline empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, sprockets

I am using Rails 5.2 
I am trying to access the path of an image as follow:

```
<%=  image_path(@pin.image)%>
```

I am getting the following error message in the terminal.

Did I just forget to set something in the config.assets.paths? or wrong setting for the sprockets?

Started GET "/pins/2" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-07-18 20:53:06 +0900
   (1.0ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations"."version" FROM "schema_migrations" ORDER BY "schema_migrations"."version" ASC
  ↳ /Users/computer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
Processing by PinsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"2"}
  Pin Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "pins".* FROM "pins" WHERE "pins"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/pins_controller.rb:67
  Rendering pins/show.html.erb within layouts/application
  ActiveStorage::Attachment Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "active_storage_attachments".* FROM "active_storage_attachments" WHERE "active_storage_attachments"."record_id" = ? AND "active_storage_attachments"."record_type" = ? AND "active_storage_attachments"."name" = ? LIMIT ?  [["record_id", 2], ["record_type", "Pin"], ["name", "image"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/pins/show.html.erb:8
  ActiveStorage::Blob Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "active_storage_blobs".* FROM "active_storage_blobs" WHERE "active_storage_blobs"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/pins/show.html.erb:8
  Rendered pins/show.html.erb within layouts/application (174.0ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 224ms (ActiveRecord: 3.3ms)

ActionView::Template::Error (The asset "" is not present in the asset pipeline.):

```
  6: </p>
  7: 
  8: <%= image_tag(@pin.image) %>
  9: <%=  image_path(@pin.image)%>
 10: 
 11: 
 12:
```

app/views/pins/show.html.erb:9:in `_app_views_pins_show_html_erb__253993838852336219_70195426237620'

Answer (score 0):

I just solved my problem by using instead :

```
<%=  rails_blob_url(@pin.image)%>
```

Is it a correct way to proceed ?